# Creating Table for Categories and SubCategories

Tags: sql, asp.net

I want to create a single table for Categories and SubCategories.

Also there will be other columns such as CategoriesName and SubCategoriesName.

When Implementing on this on front end, I want the data to be properly populated for each categories and subcategories correctly.

Comment: This doesn't have a specific problem and is too broad. Please let us know what your specific issue is, what error messages you are getting, what you have tried, etc.

Comment: Have you read your question? What possibly are we meant to suggest given such little information? You have *physically* given only **two column headings** to go on? All ***I*** can tell you is that you should be splitting that into two seperate tables (with a foreign key).

Comment: @jbutler483: I want a column which will have CategoryID to map with SubCategory.Rest other columns I can include.

Comment: @JasonW: I din't still tried working on it. Need your guidance to actually start in correct way

Comment: Its new question as I such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following

1- from the ms-sql side and to create the table

```
create table [dbo].[categories](
    id int identity(1,1) not null,
    name nvarchar(50) not null,
    parent int null,
 constraint [pk_categories] primary key clustered ( id asc))

go

alter table [dbo].[categories]  with check add  constraint [fk_subcategories] foreign key(parent)
references [dbo].[categories] ([id])
go

alter table [dbo].[categories] check constraint [fk_subcategories]
go
```

the above code will create a table called categories for you and it contains a parent field that will build the relation between the category and its sub categories

2- from the asp.net ( assuming that you are using asp.net application)

add a page and put 2 dropdownlist and call them the following : categoryDropDownList and subCategoryDropDownList and add GridView and call it dataGridView

3- on the page code make the following to populate the first dropdown list

```
var sql="Select * from dbo.categories where parent is null";
 var connection=new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Your connectionstring");
 var adapter=new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql,connection);
 var table =new DataTable();
 adapter.Fill(table); 
 categoryDropDownList.DataSource=table;
 catagoryDropDwonList.Databind();
```

4- on selected index change of catagoryDropDownList in order to populate the second dropdownlist, you do the following:

```
var sql=string.Format("Select * from dbo.categories where parent={0}",categoryDropDownList.SelectedIndex); 

// here you are calling to retrieve all the categories with parent from the category dropdown list, which means you will get all sub categories of the selected category from category list

 var connection=new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Your connectionstring");
 var adapter=new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sql,connection);
 var table =new DataTable();
 adapter.Fill(table); 
 subCategoryDropDownList.DataSource=table;
 subCatagoryDropDwonList.Databind();
```

5- on selected index change of subCatagoryDropDownList you do the necessary coding to populate the datagrid

hope this will help you

Comment: Hasan: I am using SQL statement to create a table.

Comment: how you will display the data? in a treeview ?

Comment: I will display the Categories and Sub categories in dropdownlist. And Subcategories will have a sheet uploaded which will be displayed in a gridview. The Excel sheet will be displayed on the SubCategories ID for each Category in Grids

Comment: so you have 2 cascading dropdownlist one for categories and other for subcategories that will be filled based on the category dropdownlist? and when you select the sub category, a gridview will be populated? if so i can edit the answer to show you how to do this

Comment: yes sure, please do the needful.I dont have much Idea about handling the DB. Thanks

Comment: I am going to implement your answer here, just need one clarification. Can I add more columns into it. For ex: I want to add CategoryName and SubCategoryName ?

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, just the sub categories are not been getting displayed other than first listItem